# Looping through dataframe rows and compare them

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, if-statement

I am working with a huge dataframe and I want to loop through rows and compare them.
If Value and DATE are the same in different rows I would like to merge them doing some statistics, eg, minimum of minimums etc..

```
Value   MIN    MAX   MEAN     STD    DATE
0       -2460  -454  -1413.1  254.8  20181223
1       -2361   619  -1348.3  443.0  20181223
0       -2677  -483  -1626.3  258.8  20181227
1       -2629   256  -1477.5  378.0  20181227
2       -2682   598  -1486.0  319.4  20181227
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need `groupby.min`. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Please also add what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.

```
df = pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
df

df.groupby(['Value'])['MIN'].min()


df.groupby(['Value'])[['MIN','MAX','MEAN','STD']].min()
```